# Drawing multiple graphs side by side in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, graphs

I'd like to make a picture of a triangle, a square, and a pentagon (C_3, C_4, C_5 in standard graph theory vocabulary) appearing side by side in Tikz. Drawing them individually I can do but I'm not sure how to get them side by side?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: One thing you can always to is to put these things in different scopes with different `xshift`s. This should do it for you if you know how to draw the individual pictures.

Comment: why you not show us, what you do so far? help us to help ypu!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\draw[rotate=90] (0,0) -- ++(0:2)--++(120:2)--cycle;
\draw[xshift=2cm,rotate=-18] (0,0)--++(0:2cm)--++(72:2)--++(144:2)--++(216:2)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- ++(0:2)--++(120:2)--cycle;
\draw[xshift=2.5cm] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\draw[xshift=6cm] (0,0)--++(0:2cm)--++(72:2)--++(144:2)--++(216:2)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \a in {3,...,5}{
\draw[red, dashed] (\a*2,0) circle(0.5cm);
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\a, draw,
inner sep=0.3535cm] at (\a*2,0) {};
}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
\foreach \a in {3,...,5}{
\draw[red, dashed] (\a*2,0) circle(0.5cm);
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\a, minimum size=1cm, draw] at (\a*2,0) {};
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many compliments for your recent excellent works with LaTeX.